# background color to an element which is positioned before the identified tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors, background-color, drop-down-menu

i'm trying to add a background color to a element which is positioned before the identified tag. for example, i know the class of one elment and i have a list like below.

```
<ul id="one">
  <li><a href='#'>text0</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>text1</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>text2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>text3</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="item-1"><a href='#' class='identified'>item1</a></li>
        <li class="item-2"><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
        <li class="item-3"><a href='#'>item3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-c">C</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>
```

now i want to assign a background color to the 1st level element if i know class='identified' i want to cange the background color of text1 
what can i do to make this work.?

Comment: Your code was copied from [here](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), which is where the answer is.. p.s. what have you tried?

Comment: ah, it was in another page too. i will try this thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jQuery `closest` method.

```
$('li.identified').closest('ul').closest('ul').prev().css('background', 'red');
```

`.closest()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

Well "text1" is the first anchor element belonging to the ".identified" element's parent's parent's parent's parent's parent. So you can do this:

```
$(".identified").parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()
                .children("a").css({"background-color" : "blue" });
```

(Fix the actual CSS change as appropriate, and double-check that I counted the parents correctly.)

But the above is kind of brittle because it relies on knowing exactly how many levels belong to the heirarchy. If you could assign a class to all of your top level `li` elements, say a "topMenu" class, then you could do this:

```
$(".identified").closest(".topMenu")
                .children("a").css({"background-color":"blue"});
```

The [`.closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) goes up through the DOM tree from the current element until it finds one matching the supplied selector.

EDIT: Sorry, you don't need to add a class, I just realised there's already enough information in your markup to directly select the appropriate ancestor `li` element:

```
$(".identified").closest("#one > li")
                .children("a").css({"background-color":"red"});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WVd8W/